# Select value not selected in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this html markup:

```
    <div ng-repeat="prop in props" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Property {{$index + 1}} ({{prop.AddressLine1}})</label><div class="col-md-8">
       <select ng-model="prop.Grade" class="form-control" ng-options="opt.name for opt in propGradings track by opt.id">                                                                       <option ng-selected="{{option.id == prop.Grade}}" ng-repeat="option in propGradings" ng-value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
```

This static array to fill in the dropdown:

```
$scope.propGradings = [{ name: "1", id: 1 }, { name: "2", id: 2 }, { name: "3", id: 3 }, { name: "4", id: 4 }];
```

I'm able to load the items in the dropdown, but I'm not able to preselect the correct value based on the prop.Grade value.

HTML Output:

[image]

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does prop.Grade have a value? This kind of thing usually happens if the ng-model value is undefined, or is a non-string value.

Comment: What value are you putting into prop.Grade? obj or id?

Comment: @mhodges its actually int, it should be string?

Comment: integer value https://i.gyazo.com/0dbc7c3033b7cc6c2929bd6e0379464d.png @Valter

Comment: Do you want it to bind based off of the id or the name of the selected value?

Comment: both id and name actually have the same value, one is in string another in int. Give me a minute actually i'm changing the Grade type to nvarchar in the db table and I'll give another try. Will update you in a minute

Comment: Here are two ways of doing it. One with binding the id and using integers, and one with binding the name and using strings. See if this helps: http://jsbin.com/natokagiwu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @mhodges thanks, please write that as answer to mark it right

Comment: @Laziale Posted an answer. Let me know if I missed anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When selecting options from a dropdown, **type matters** for binding purposes. When using [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions), you can use **as** to bind something to the model as a non-string value. In your case, you may want to bind to the integer value of the id.

**Syntax:** `select` **as** `label` **for** `value` **in** `array`

> select: The value that gets bound to ng-model
> label: What value visibly shows up in the dropdown
> value: Current item in array
> array: Data source for generating the options

#### Example of binding to an integer value:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.props = [{Grade: 1}];
  $scope.propGradings = [{ name: "1", id: 1 }, { name: "2", id: 2 }, { name: "3", id: 3 }, { name: "4", id: 4 }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Binding with an integer value:
  <div ng-repeat="prop in props" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Property {{$index + 1}} ({{prop.AddressLine1}})</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <select ng-model="prop.Grade" class="form-control" ng-options="opt.id as opt.name for opt in propGradings">
        <option ng-selected="{{option.id == prop.Grade}}" ng-repeat="option in propGradings" ng-value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Example of binding to a string value:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
  $scope.props = [{Grade: "1"}];
  $scope.propGradings = [{ name: "1", id: 1 }, { name: "2", id: 2 }, { name: "3", id: 3 }, { name: "4", id: 4 }];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Binding with a string value:
  <div ng-repeat="prop in props" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Property {{$index + 1}} ({{prop.AddressLine1}})</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <select ng-model="prop.Grade" class="form-control" ng-options="opt.name as opt.name for opt in propGradings">
        <option ng-selected="{{option.id == prop.Grade}}" ng-repeat="option in propGradings" ng-value="{{option.id}}">{{option.name}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```